She locked the door securely behind her

She locked the door securely behind her.

What's the meaing of the sentence? She locked the door with her back towards the door?
Or there was a door behind her and she locked the door with her front towards the door as normally?

"behind her" implies that she walked through the (open) door, closed and locked it, then kept walking, leaving the door behind.  It does not imply that she was facing a particular direction as she was locking it (although it would be normal to face towards the door while doing so.)

It is an interesting sentence because "securely" probably does not confer the manner of her action -- she may have closed it carefully, or quickly, or silently -- but rather the state of the door after the act: The door then was securely closed. It resembles Joseph Conrad's "the tranquil waterway leading to the uttermost ends of the earth flowed sombre under an overcast sky..." "Sombre" is not the manner of flowing, it is its manner of overall being or appearance. The sentence in the question does not strike me as wrong though, so I'm not sure.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: For a door you're thinking of "fixed or fastened so as not to give way, become loose, or be lost", but secure also means "certain to remain safe and unthreatened". The latter is the manner in which she closed the door: making certain that it would remain closed and not be opened by someone who shouldn't be opening it. It functionally means the same thing, she closed the door securely, so that the door would be secure. "Securely" in this sentence refers to her manner, just like "quickly" or "carelessly" would. It just happens to also match another definition of the word.

@Flater I don't buy it. The door is secure? Not really -- it is actually quite exposed. The gold in the room behind it is secure though, because the door takes all the flak! The door is, hopefully, securely locked which is why "locking securely" sounds right.

Also, "securely" can hardly be the manner in which she closed the door. She may be securely enjoying a view from a cliff because she is in a harness, but she does not enjoy any special protection while she is locking the door.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica In "She locked the door securely.", 'securely' modifies the whole sentence or the predicative part of "locked the door".

@Flater I asked a question over at English about this.

It expresses the idea that after locking the door she turned her back to the door and walked away.

Before leaving the house for the day, she locked the door behind her.

She left the door in a locked state.

Is this a poetic expression? I think "she locked the door." is enough. Why should there be  'behind her;?

It expresses departure.  It's not "poetic" but an everyday phrase.

As well as indicating departure, it commonly indicates that the person went out through the door, and locked it afterwards, then left.

@gomadeng One example might be as a command: "close the door" without context could be "close it right now", while "close the door behind you" is "as you are about to leave, close the door".

Not particularly poetic. "I'm going to McDonald's. Want a coffee?" "No thanks. Hey, can you close the door behind you?"

It doesn't express the idea that she turned her back to the door after closing it. Case in point: if she was inside the house, walked up to the door, closed it, and then turned around to walk away, you would not say "she closed the door behind her". It expresses that she first walked through the door, only to then close is. The door is behind her in terms of where she was intending to travel, regardless of the direction she faces precisely at the time of shutting it, or the direction she faces afterwards.

She locked the door behind her, means something like: After walking through the door, she locked it and then continued to walk away. There's a sense that locking the door wasn't her primary goal, but rather something she did as part of going somewhere else—usually involving entering or leaving through that door.
(I omitted “securely,” because it sounds like that's not part of your question. It's just acting as a normal adverb, telling us the manner in which she locked the door.)
In this sentence, “behind her” isn't really telling us about a location. Yes, the door was probably behind her when she started walking away again, but that little prepositional phrase is mostly there to work with the verb lock to alter its meaning. This construction is very closely related to something called a phrasal verb: a combination of a verb and a preposition that often means something completely different from the verb on its own.
A classic example of phrasal verbs are hit, hit up, and hit on. Alex hit Bob, means that Alex struck Bob. Alex hit up Bob, or more commonly Alex hit Bob up, means that Alex visited Bob (often to ask for a favor). Alex hit on Bob, means that Alex flirted with Bob.
There's no real logic to these combinations of verbs, prepositions, and meanings—if there ever was, it's long since forgotten by modern speakers. They're just fixed pairs that English speakers understand as independent verbs, and English learners are stuck learning them by rote. (Sorry.)
I'm not entirely sure if lock behind actually counts as a phrasal verb. Its meaning still has to do with locking something, and the door is in fact behind the subject at some point in the action. Also, there are parallel phrases like close behind and shut behind that work similarly, which isn't usually the case with phrasal verbs. But as you've seen, the meaning is greater than the verb and preposition would indicate on their own. Either way, I think it would be helpful to think of lock behind as something more like a phrasal verb than not, and to add it to your growing catalog of special verb-preposition pairs in English.

"she locked the door [as she went]" might be a good example for a replacement phrase to explain the use of "behind her"


Is this sentence possible: She locked the door behind her as she went. ? 2. Is this sentence possible: She locked the door as she went behind her. ?


@gomadeng Yes for first. The second is grammatical but doesn't mean what you want. The prepositional phrase behind her winds up tied to went rather than locked, so it sounds like the subject locked the door as she moved to stand behind another woman.

@gomadeng I might speak the second out loud (meaning the first) if I were distracted or tired, but that would be a mistake and I'd probably have to clarify.

@gomadeng And just to clarify, as she went isn't a perfect replacement, because she could also lock the door behind her as part of arriving somewhere rather than just leaving. For example: She came into the bedroom and locked the door behind her. It's also a phrase joined with a conjunction (as) rather than a prepositional phrase like behind her.
